# Good licenses for in-house projects

Tags: licensing

I would like to find out if there is any type of license with the following requirements:

- The author decides with whom to share the code (this would be optional)
- You are free the copy any part of the code
- If you modify the program, you must give it back
- The author controls distribution

... or any combination of the above. Many companies build interesting in-house software projects. One problem with these tools is that they are built with the budget of one department, therefore not many managers will like to spend their budget building a completely free (GPL/BSD) tool. If they sacrifice their own budget, they might have some second thoughts before sharing the code with other departments that were not involved in the costs.

I think there must be out there some licenses that promote good relations between departments. Something of the spirit of "we give you our code, but if you improve it, you must give it back to us/everyone". At the same time the license should provide some control on distribution in order to keep the code free within a company.

LGPL could be a great example, the only problem is that the author has no control on distribution. I know that if the teams keep the binaries inside the company the code will never go public, but many managers would rather prefer some real control on the distribution as a mean to protect their effort.

I am looking for a license that promotes sharing within a company departments but only one person/department should have the decision if it can be shared for free with the outside world.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking the wrong approach. Licenses are useful when transferring copyrighted works between legal entities, but departments within a company are all part of the same legal entity. The R&D department can't sue the sales department for releasing something without permission.

The appropriate way to handle this is through management/policy.

Comment: Thanks! Very good point about all departments being the same legal entity. I also believe that good management is the best solution, but that is also hard to find. I never thought about who can sue each other. I was thinking more in the symbolic meaning found in the share-a-like spirit of open source licenses. Your answer really kills my expectations, but I still hope to find hints for a license that promotes cooperation between departments. Maybe it will really be LGPL with the commitment of everyone to keep the binaries inside... but it would be a very bad thing if someone breaks the rule

Comment: I've just given you one vote. Even it my question has the wrong approach, I have learned something interesting about licensing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [GNU Affero GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html).

As always if license is not enough for you You could modify its content rename it as myAffero and redistribute your software with it.

Comment: Nope. The FSF lets you use the AGPL as-is only. Making variants of the AGPL is not permitted.